# employeeNumber in FreeIPA/IPA using ldapsearch

Tags: openldap, freeipa

Is there a way to use the ldapsearch against FreeIPA to return the uid AND employeeNumber?

Using a simple ldapsearch does not expose all the attributes. Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In freeIPA, you can control which attributes are exposed -- and easily done via the web UI. That was needed for employeeNumber which solved this. Hopefully, this'll help others.